# Loop through all firestore documents in a collection AND update them in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to iterate through all the documents in the "exercise" collection and update them with new values. I wrote a function that works but it's an inefficient solution. This is the whole function:

```
final thisWorkout = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('workouts')
  .doc(widget.docRef!.id);

final allExercises = await thisWorkout.collection('exercise').get();

thisWorkout.update({
    'name': workoutName,
  });

  List allIds = [];

  allExercises.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot value) {
    allIds.add(value.reference.id);
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < exercises.length; i++) {
    thisWorkout.collection('exercise').doc(allIds[i]).set(exercises[i]);
  }
```

This is the portion of the function that is inefficient:

```
List allIds = [];

  allExercises.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot value) {
    allIds.add(value.reference.id);
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < exercises.length; i++) {
    thisWorkout.collection('exercise').doc(allIds[i]).set(exercises[i]);
  }
```

Is there a way to just iterate through each doc AND update it without having store all the ids then run a separate for loop for the update?

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
allExercises.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot value) {
  thisWorkout.collection('exercise').doc(value.reference.id).set(exercises[i]);
});
```

Comment: Yes i tried something like this with a manual "iteration" int variable that increased by 1 for each loop but the "exercises" list order was not synced with the order of the foreach documents, so it would overwrite the wrong data on the document.

Comment: Ah i think i know why. I had was adding the docs to the exercises list with the add function, i could just switch it with insert and the order should be in sync. Thanks